# Use of the '*' symbol

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am looking at the definition of a 'Euclidean domain', on p.51 of the book 'Polynomial Algorithms in Computer Algebra', by F. Winkler.  The definition states :-

"A Euclidean domain (ED) D is an integral domain together with a *degree function* deg:
D* ---> N0, such that:-

a. deg(a.b) >= deg(a) for all a,b *elements of* D*,

b. (division property) for all a,b *elements of* D, b *not equal to* 0, there exists a 
    *quotient* q and a *remainder* r in D such that a = q.b + r and 
    (r = 0 or deg(r) < deg(b))"

(Here N0 refers to the set of natural numbers including zero)

My question is simply, what does D* mean?  I can find no reference in the book to the use of the asterix. Any idea?  I'm assuming its a subfield?

Comment: $D^{\ast} = D\setminus\{0\}$ in this context. Sometimes it refers to the set of units of the ring $D$

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as @Prahlad suggested $D^*$ simply means the Ring without the identity of summation.

I'll give you the definition by M. Artin (Algebra 2nd Edition), so that you have a second reference to work with:

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks @Prahlad